# Can't access Restlet File in Netsuite?

Tags: javascript, php, netsuite

I created Employee account called user under Netsuite admin account

When i call restlet method using user account credentials doesn't give any response.(empty response)

but when i call restlet method with same request using Admin account credentials it returns the expected response.

My Suspect:
user account credentials can't access the restlet script because it doesn't give any response 
if i give correct script id & deployment id it return empty response.
if i give wrong script id or deployment id it return the following output:

```
Array
(
[error] => Array
    (
        [code] => SSS_INVALID_SCRIPTLET_ID
        [message] => That Suitelet is invalid, disabled, or no longer exists.
    )

)
```

> Note: Here Admin & User has the same Role. Restlet script installed in Admin account using Bundle.

Any idea why i can't access the restlet using user account credentials?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that in your Script Deployment record the Status field is set to Released, and in the Audience sublist, the Employees and/or Roles you want to make the Restlet available to are selected.

Comment: Yes i ensured Script deployment is set to Released. and also checked all roles & all employees. but no luck @michoel

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, the issue appears to be the Suitelet being called by the RESTlet and not the RESTlet itself.  Make sure that the deployment of the Suitelet being called is released as @michoel said.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the deployment ensuring the Audience, Roles and Released Status are kept and try accessing the RESTlet from the new deployment.

I have experienced issues like the one you mentioned, I suspect Netsuite caches the permissions.