# How to remove bundle access to particular employee in Netsuite?

Tags: bundle, netsuite

I am the administrator of Netsuite Account. I have installed suite bundle. I have created 5 employees under the same role. But i want restrict to access the suite bundle for one employee. 4 can access the netsuite bundle. Remaining one should not access the suite bundle.

How to do that?

i am facing similar issue asked in the post
[Can't access Restlet File in Netsuite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778719/cant-access-restlet-file-in-netsuite)
But i asked in different way.

Comment: Which particular bundle component are you trying to restrict the users?

Comment: Not particular component, one bundle fully. Ex: ABC is the bundle name, the user should not access that(ABC) bundle.